# tensorflow TypeError and ValueError

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hallo everyone,

I'm trying running my program on a new computer, but I got all those errors and warning. From the results, it seems like all the problems come from tensorflow.

I have also tried running this program on other computer, it is fine.

The first problem is that I cannot figure out what is those warnings mean, on other computer there are no those warnings.

```
$ ./run_av.sh
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/io_utils.py:208: tf_record_iterator (from tensorflow.python.lib.io.tf_record) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use eager execution and: 
`tf.data.TFRecordDataset(path)`
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/io_utils.py:183: to_int64 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py:1419: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/video.py:27: conv2d (from tensorflow.python.layers.convolutional) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use keras.layers.conv2d instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/video.py:11: batch_normalization (from tensorflow.python.layers.normalization) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use keras.layers.batch_normalization instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/cells.py:19: LSTMCell.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This class is equivalent as tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell, and will be replaced by that in Tensorflow 2.0.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/cells.py:92: MultiRNNCell.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn_cell_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
This class is equivalent as tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells, and will be replaced by that in Tensorflow 2.0.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/encoder.py:81: dynamic_rnn (from tensorflow.python.ops.rnn) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `keras.layers.RNN(cell)`, which is equivalent to this API
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py:626: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py:1259: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/helper.py:311: Bernoulli.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.distributions.bernoulli) is deprecated and will be removed after 2019-01-01.
Instructions for updating:
The TensorFlow Distributions library has moved to TensorFlow Probability (https://github.com/tensorflow/probability). You should update all references to use `tfp.distributions` instead of `tf.distributions`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/distributions/bernoulli.py:97: Distribution.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.distributions.distribution) is deprecated and will be removed after 2019-01-01.
Instructions for updating:
The TensorFlow Distributions library has moved to TensorFlow Probability (https://github.com/tensorflow/probability). You should update all references to use `tfp.distributions` instead of `tf.distributions`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/seq2seq/python/ops/helper.py:314: Categorical.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.distributions.categorical) is deprecated and will be removed after 2019-01-01.
Instructions for updating:
The TensorFlow Distributions library has moved to TensorFlow Probability (https://github.com/tensorflow/probability). You should update all references to use `tfp.distributions` instead of `tf.distributions`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/distributions/categorical.py:278: multinomial (from tensorflow.python.ops.random_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.random.categorical instead.
/home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py:110: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 511, in _apply_op_helper
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1175, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 977, in _TensorTensorConversionFunction
    (dtype.name, t.dtype.name, str(t)))
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype resource: 'Tensor("Decoder/video/Encoder/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/kernel/AMSGrad:0", shape=(), dtype=resource)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "experiment_tcd_av.py", line 64, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "experiment_tcd_av.py", line 47, in main
    num_gpus=1,
  File "/home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/avsr.py", line 193, in __init__
    self._create_models()
  File "/home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/avsr.py", line 381, in _create_models
    batch_size=self._hparams.batch_size[0])
  File "/home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/avsr.py", line 418, in _make_model
    hparams=self._hparams
  File "/home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/seq2seq.py", line 21, in __init__
    self._make_decoder()
  File "/home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/seq2seq.py", line 113, in _make_decoder
    hparams=self._hparams
  File "/home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/decoder_bimodal.py", line 51, in __init__
    self._init_decoder()
  File "/home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/decoder_bimodal.py", line 116, in _init_decoder
    self._init_optimiser()
  File "/home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/decoder_bimodal.py", line 514, in _init_optimiser
    zip(gradients, variables), global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
  File "/home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 612, in apply_gradients
    update_ops.append(processor.update_op(self, grad))
  File "/home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 171, in update_op
    update_op = optimizer._resource_apply_dense(g, self._v)
  File "/home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/AMSGrad.py", line 96, in _resource_apply_dense
    m_t = state_ops.assign(m, beta1_t * m + m_scaled_g_values, use_locking=self._use_locking)
  File "/home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 812, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "/home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1078, in _mul_dispatch
    return gen_math_ops.mul(x, y, name=name)
  File "/home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 5860, in mul
    "Mul", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "/home/wentao/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 547, in _apply_op_helper
    inferred_from[input_arg.type_attr]))
TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type resource that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'.
Exception ignored in: <bound method AVSR.__del__ of <avsr.avsr.AVSR object at 0x7f3db42332b0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wentao/Sigmedia-AVSR-LRS2/avsr/avsr.py", line 198, in __del__
    self._train_session.close()
AttributeError: 'AVSR' object has no attribute '_train_session'
```

And for the ValueError and TypeError, I can't figure out why.

I have just used "pip3 install tensorflow" install tensorflow, but it seems something wrong,

Please help me or give me some advises to fix it , thank you

Comment: Have a look at your code, go through all of those bits of code that you're being warned about and change them to be compatible with future versions of tensorflow, and fix the incorrect use of AVSR objects. This is due to different versions of the library installed on different machines. If you struggle to do this you could come back and ask for help if you include some code?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I want to ask, if you know, which library is wrong?

Comment: What is your TF version and what API version was used when the code was originally written? Maybe downgrade TF version.